# How to add static data to a typescript model class

Tags: typescript

I have a requirement to create a model class in typescript, this is my data.

```
A-E
  Automative
  Chemicals
  Energy

F-O
 Forest Product
 Industrial
 Mining

P-Z
 Retail
 Software Platform
 Unilites
```

For this data, I have created below model class

```
export class Industries 
{
  alphaIndex: string = '';
  industries: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(alphaIndex: string, industries: []) {
    this.alphaIndex = alphaIndex;
    this.industries = industries; 
  }
}
```

When I want to add data in it, getting error

```
let record = new Industries ({alphaIndex: 'A-E', industries: ['Automative','Chemicals']});
this.industries.push(record);
```

Getting below below error

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) home.component.ts(28, 35): An argument for 'industries' was not provided
```

This is correct model for provided data ? How can I add data to my model ?

Comment: It should be `new Industries("A-E", [...])`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in an object into the constructor

Instead you should pass as separate variables

```
let record = new Industries ('A-E',['Automative','Chemicals']);
this.industries.push(record);
```

if you wanted to have it as an object type param then you would need to do this

```
export interface IIndustryParam {
   alphaIndex : string;
   industries: Array<string>;
}

export class Industries 
{
  alphaIndex: string = '';
  industries: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(industryParam : IIndustryParam) {
    this.alphaIndex = industryParam.alphaIndex;
    this.industries = industryParam.industries; 
  }
}

let record = new Industries ({alphaIndex: 'A-E', industries: ['Automative','Chemicals']});
this.industries.push(record);
```

Comment: For 2nd argument it says `Argument of type '[string, string]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.
  Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 0`

Comment: Try the above sorry

Comment: You may need to change the type from [] to Array<string> or string[]

Comment: By that I mean change `constructor(alphaIndex: string, industries: []) {` to `constructor(alphaIndex: string, industries: string[]) {`

Comment: Now it seems working. Is my model class correct for given data structure ? And I must need to use interface along with model class ?

Comment: Yeah it looks fine, either of the solutions in my answer will work. The reason it wasn't working the first time is your passing in the params as an object. Which is where the interface comes in to type define that object. You can get rid of it as in my first example and just pass them as separate params though.